# Syntax for passing a number of values that allows for template deduction

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template <size_t s>
void print_elements(const array<int, s> &a)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++)
        cout << i << ": " << a[i] << '\n';
    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print_elements<3>({0,5,2});
    print_elements(std::array{0,5,2});
    // print_elements({0,5,2}); - does not work
}
```

I am currently working with code like this. I have to call `print_elements` very often, and all the `std::array` make my code hard to read by now. I was wondering if there is some syntax that would allow me to use just `print_elements({0,5,2})`, and still deduce the number 3 correctly in the template.

Comment: Either `std::vector<int>` or `std::initializer_list<int>` as the parameter?

Comment: I do still need to deduce the right number for the template (my actual problem requires the number of elements to be typesafe)

Comment: Why is your primary goal "deduce the number 3 correctly" instead of "make `print_elements` do what it is supposed to do"?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need it, but you could use `const T (&arr)[N]` (with `T` and `N` being template parameters).